# Find first instance of each group of divs containing same text

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to set CSS only on the first `.event` in each group of divs, which has an `a` with the same text in it.

In the example, these should be only the 1st and 3rd divs (because the first `.event` is the first of divs with an `a` with text `first event`, and the third `.event` is the first of divs with an `a` with text `second event`).

I tried this code but didn't work:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  var eventitle = $(".event .title a").text();
  $(".event .title a:contains(" + eventitle + ")").each(function() {
    var parenter = $(this).closest(".event");
    $(parenter).first().css("color", "red");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="event">
  <div class="title">
    <a href="#">first event</a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="event">
  <div class="title">
    <a href="#">first event</a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="event">
  <div class="title">
    <a href="#">second event</a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="event">
  <div class="title">
    <a href="#">second event</a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="event">
  <div class="title">
    <a href="#">second event</a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="event">
  <div class="title">
    <a href="#">second event</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not quite certain what your current logic is attempting to do, but it's flawed in several ways.

Given that the text of the elements is already in order, the simplest way to achieve what you require is to compare the text of the previous element to the current one in the loop. If they are different then you can add the class to change the colour of the text, something like this:

```js
var prevText = '';
$('.event .title a').each(function() {
  var text = $(this).text().trim();
  $(this).closest('.event').toggleClass('foo', prevText != text);
  prevText = text;
});
```

```css
.foo a {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="event">
  <div class="title">
    <a href="#">first event</a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="event">
  <div class="title">
    <a href="#">first event</a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="event">
  <div class="title">
    <a href="#">second event</a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="event">
  <div class="title">
    <a href="#">second event</a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="event">
  <div class="title">
    <a href="#">second event</a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="event">
  <div class="title">
    <a href="#">second event</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Note that for the text of the `a` to actually be changed by the class on the parent element you'll need to set the CSS selector explicitly to `.event a`.

*Update:*

> Thanks, but the div can be ordered not one after the other. They can be spread around the loop

In this case you could use an array to maintain a list of text of the `a` elements you've already traversed through. If the array does not contain the text of the current element, add the class.

```js
var titles = [];
$('.event .title a').each(function() {
  var text = $(this).text().trim();
  if (titles.indexOf(text) == -1) {
    $(this).closest('.event').addClass('foo');
    titles.push(text);
  }
});
```

```css
.foo a {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="event">
  <div class="title">
    <a href="#">first event</a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="event">
  <div class="title">
    <a href="#">second event</a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="event">
  <div class="title">
    <a href="#">second event</a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="event">
  <div class="title">
    <a href="#">second event</a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="event">
  <div class="title">
    <a href="#">first event</a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="event">
  <div class="title">
    <a href="#">third event</a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="event">
  <div class="title">
    <a href="#">second event</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thx - but the div can be ordered not one after the other. they can be spread around the loop.

Comment: Ok, I updated the answer to show you how to work around that

Comment: perfect! da best <3

Comment: now - i hid all ".event" divs which aren't ".foo". when i click on ".foo", i want all ".event" div with same ".event .title a" text to reappear. is this possible?

Comment: Yes, but I'd suggest starting a new question for it.

Comment: (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53516570/toggle-only-div-containing-same-text)