# Toggle only div containing same text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

**HTML:**

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="event">
  <div class="clicker">
    click
  </div>
  <div class="title">
    <a href="#">first event</a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="event">
  <div class="clicker">
    click
  </div>
  <div class="title">
    <a href="#">first event</a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="event">
  <div class="clicker">
    click
  </div>
  <div class="title">
    <a href="#">second event</a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="event">
  <div class="clicker">
    click
  </div>
  <div class="title">
    <a href="#">second event</a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="event">
  <div class="clicker">
    click
  </div>
  <div class="title">
    <a href="#">second event</a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="event">
  <div class="clicker">
    click
  </div>
  <div class="title">
    <a href="#">second event</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

This gives me a `foo` class for every first instance of `event` in a group with the `a` tag with the same text.

Now I would like that, whenever I click a `clicker`, I want all the `.event` divs with same `.event .title a` text to reappear.

(code updated to show proper structure and why the solution didn't work. whenever i click on "clicker", it applies the code to ALL events)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to attach a click event to the `event` class, then when the user clicks the div you could get the text of the anchor and use `contains` selector to filter the event with the same title text :

```js
$('.event').click(function() {
  $('.event a:contains(' + $('a', this).text() + ')').closest('.event').toggleClass('foo');
});
```

```css
.foo {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="event">
  <div class="title">
    <a href="#">first event</a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="event">
  <div class="title">
    <a href="#">first event</a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="event">
  <div class="title">
    <a href="#">second event</a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="event">
  <div class="title">
    <a href="#">second event</a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="event">
  <div class="title">
    <a href="#">second event</a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="event">
  <div class="title">
    <a href="#">second event</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thx! almost works - because what i need is to add a class not the the actual `a` but to the parent `event`. and whenever i try to do that, it gives the class to ALL divs and not just the ones with `a` with same text in them.

Comment: i updated the html to show you the problem. whenever i click `clicker`, the jquery you wrote applies to all `event` divs. thx!

Comment: I have tried it with the same JS and new HTML, it works, take a look to https://jsfiddle.net/o9ezaLhc/1/

Comment: that's because you're clicking on the event and not an element within the event (which is what i was trying to do). once i change the click event to `.clicker` - the code stops working. tx for all the effort!

Comment: Good job... Glad I could help.